# Dynamically build dictionary from columns specified at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I have been told I need to use a mapping table instead of a hardcoded dictionary I made.  There has to be a better method than the code below to get a 3 column table into a dictionary?

Mapping table

```
AgentGrp, Property, TimeZone  #Headers
HollyWoodAgent  Sunset  PST
UnionSquareAgent UnionSquare PST
```

Turns into the following dictionary:

```
{'HollyWoodAgent': ['Sunset', 'PST'], 'UnionSquareAgent': ['UnionSquare', 'PST']}
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import datetime
import sys
import csv

VipAgent = "{"

finalSql = "SELECT  agentgrp, property, timezone FROM sandbox_dev.agentgrp_map;"

colcnt = 0

try:

    conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=Dev")

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(finalSql)
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        VipAgent += "'" + row.prop + "VipAgent':['" + row.prop + "','" + row.tz + "'],"
        colcnt = colcnt + 1
        if(colcnt==3):
            VipAgent = VipAgent + "\n"
            colcnt = 0

except my.Error as e:
    print(e)

VipAgent = VipAgent[:-1] + "}"

Dict = eval(VipAgent)

print(Dict)
```

I do get the values as expected.  There has to be a better python way out there.

Comment: I removed the file line -- it was a remnant from a testing phase.

Answer (score 0):

We'll take it as given that you read the "mapping table" from a file into a Python list similar to this one

```python
item_map = ['AgentGrp', 'Property', 'TimeZone']
```

Once you've executed your SELECT query

```python
cursor.execute(finalSql)
```

then you can build your `dict` like so:

```python
result_dict = {}
while (True):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if (row):
        result_dict[row.__getattribute__(item_map[0])] = \
                [row.__getattribute__(x) for x in item_map[1:]]
    else:
        break
print(result_dict)
# {'HollyWoodAgent': ['Sunset', 'PST'], 'UnionSquareAgent': ['UnionSquare', 'PST']}
```

The trick is to use `row.__getattribute__`, e.g., `row.__getattribute__('column_name')` instead of hard-coding `row.column_name`.